# Did Scheme have macros prior to R4RS?

Tags: macros, scheme

My understanding of the history of Scheme macros is as follows:

- R4RS introduced macros in the appendix. This was an expansion to the language rather than a part of the standard. It is essentially a library that appears in the R4RS document.
- R5RS used a similar system to R4RS, but it was entirely a part of the standard rather than an extension.
- R6RS and R7RS (small) have made minor upgrades/changes, but nothing substantial.
- Any Scheme before R4RS did not feature any macros, except for fringe external libraries.

Is this correct? It seems generally right when I search through R4RS and anything after, but I'm struggling to find an easily-searchable copy of R3RS.

Comment: macros in scheme are an incredible difficult topic.  On the other hand, your question is not targeted to something specific.

Comment: @alinsoar -- the question seems pretty specific to me: "_Did Scheme have macros prior to R4RS?_"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scheme *implementations* had macros from the beginning, but the first real standard was R2RS, which did not include a macro system in the specification.

The original SCHEME paper, "*SCHEME: An Interpreter for Extended Lambda Calculus*" (AIM-349, 1975), also known as R0RS, presented a SCHEME interpreter written in MacLISP. Even this early description of a SCHEME interpreter discusses macros:

> ...SCHEME has a class of primitives known as `AMACROS`. These are similar to MacLISP `MACRO`s, in that they are expanded into equivalent code before being executed.

The section goes on to describe some `AMACROS` which are provided with the SCHEME interpreter, including `COND`, `AND`, `OR`, `BLOCK`, and `DO`.

At the end of the paper a simple implementation of a SCHEME interpreter is presented, but the authors point out that "*the 'production version' of SCHEME is coded somewhat more intricately.*" After presenting this implementation, they write:

> `AMACRO`s are fairly complicated beasties, and have very little to do with the basic issues of the implementation of SCHEME per se, so the code for them will not be given here. `AMACRO`s behave almost exactly like MacLISP macros.

In R1RS, "*The Revised Report on SCHEME: A Dialect of Lisp*" (AIM-452, 1978), one finds:

> **C. Syntactic Extensions**
>
> SCHEME has a syntactic extension mechanism which provides a way to define an identifier to be a magic
> word, and to associate a function with that word. The function accepts
> the magic form as an argument, and produces a new form; this new form
> is then evaluated in place of the original (magic) form. This is
> precisely the same as the MacLISP macro facility.

These early macro systems were more traditional Lisp macro systems, akin to Common Lisp macros. Hygienic macros were introduced as a language extension in R4RS (1991), but not made a part of the Standard until R5RS (1998).

The early reports R0RS and R1RS were not really language standards so much as reports on the ongoing development of Scheme at MIT. In the introduction to R2RS (AIM-848, 1985) the authors say that 15 representatives of the major Scheme implementations convened to create a new standard because the implementations were starting to become too divergent. There was no macro system included in this new standard specification, but R2RS does say something about macros, including that all of the major implementations of the time did have macro systems:

> *Scheme does not have any standard facility for defining new special forms.*
>
> *Rationale:* The ability to define new special forms creates numerous problems. All current implementations of Scheme have macro facilities that solve those problems to one degree or another, but the solutions are quite different and it isn't clear at this time which solution is best....

R3RS (1986) had some similar language:

> **Macros**
>
> Scheme does not have any standard facility for defining new kinds of expressions. The ability to alter the syntax of the language creates numerous problems. All current implementations of Scheme have macro facilities that solve those problems to one degree or another, but the solutions are quite different and it isn’t clear at this time which solution is best, or indeed whether any of the solutions are truly adequate. Rather than standardize, we are encouraging implementations to continue to experiment with different solutions.

So I would say it is unfair to characterize macro systems prior to R4RS as "fringe libraries," and rather more fair to say the Scheme macro systems of the time were implementation-specific. Once macro hygiene was identified as an important issue, there was a concerted effort find the best solutions for hygienic macros within the Scheme community, and a fair bit of disagreement. This is the situation described in the above quotes from R2RS and R3RS with "*...it isn’t clear at this time which solution is best....*"

AIM-349 and AIM-452 (R0RS and R1RS) were really reports on the development of Scheme at MIT, and R2RS was the first real attempt at bringing disparate implementations together under a standard, i.e., R2RS was the first real standard for Scheme. Macros were present in the early implementations described by AIM-349 and AIM-452, but macros were left out of the standards to which implementations were required to adhere beginning with R2RS, until something approaching consensus was achieved on the topic; each implementation had its own approach to macros.

### Resources

[R3RS](https://standards.scheme.org/official/r3rs.pdf). This is a searchable pdf version, better quality than most of the scans I have seen online.

[Hygienic Macro Technology](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3386330). This is a pretty long paper by William Clinger and Mitchell Wand that describes the history of the development of hygienic macros.

Comment: I'm confused. You appear to be saying that R2RS and R3RS did not have macros as standard but that R0RS and R1RS did. Is that correct?

Comment: Sort of. R0RS and R1RS were not really standards; they were descriptions of the early ongoing development of the Scheme implementation at MIT. Others implemented versions of Scheme based on those papers, and when the need for a _standard_ arose, R2RS was that standard. The _implementations_ described in R0RS and R1RS did have macros, and as far as I can tell, all other implementations did, too. But, macro systems were not included in R2RS or R3RS because there was no consensus around how they should be designed.

Comment: IIRC, with R4RS there were still questions about the macro system, so macros were left to an appendice.

Comment: [Here is a link to a searchable pdf of R3RS](https://standards.scheme.org/official/r3rs.pdf). I read a paper once that discussed the early development of hygienic macro systems in Scheme. I am not sure, but I think it was written by Daniel Friedman, or maybe Mitchell Wand; if I can find a link I will add that, too.

Comment: Most implementations of any lisp language would at some level have "macros" and they might have them exposed to the actual language as well. Eg. like many Scheme systems have additional procedures and syntax not described in the report they are following. There are not Scheme per say since they are apart of a superset of Scheme being a dialect of that one implementation. Scheme is what is required in the reports. Eg. Scheme does not have full numeric tower until R6RS since its optional. In R4RS syntax-rules were optional  so R5RS is the earliest version you can safely use macros.

Comment: @Sylwester -- I am not sure I see your point. The answer to the question of whether Scheme had macros prior to R4RS is yes; all implementations had macro systems (not in fringe libraries as OP wondered). The first two reports included macro systems, which disappeared in R2RS. It doesn't make any sense to me to say that macros in Scheme were "_not Scheme per say_" before R2RS, since the implementations had them, unless you want to say that there was no Scheme before R2RS. It is fair to say that macro systems were not fully standardized until R5RS, but I think that is what I said in my answer.

Comment: @adabsurdum Doesn't really matter if they had. The question is if it was documented in the spec such that an implementer could implement that report with the same functionality. Eg. Racket has their core language that implements a module system and it is even available from R5RS by using identifiers not allowed in the R5RS report such that no valid scheme program would ever interact with the module system directly. A Scheme report could state that implementations had module systems, but that doesn't mean that Scheme had it since it was not standardized.

Comment: @Sylwester -- I have been trying to understand the root of your criticism, and I have made some edits in hopes of tightening things up a bit.